# Change date format on dart

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I am retrieving a date from api in this format, e.g `"2020-03-02".` But i need to a render it as this format e.g, `"Tuesday, March,2020"`. I have been unable to find consice solution to this with flutter. Any help?

Comment: I think you mean "Tuesday, March 2, 2020". It's also `dart` that is the language, not `flutter`. It looks like you need https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Specifically, it looks like you want `'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy'` as date format string (or `dd` if you want `02` instead of `2` for the day-of-month value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) plugin

```
print(DateFormat('EEEE, MMM, yyyy').parse(dateString)); // prints Tuesday, mar, 2020

//OR
print(DateFormat('yyyy, MMM, EEEE').parse(dateString)); // prints 2020, mar, Tuesday
```

Comment: I get this error. "Trying to read EEEE from 2020-03-02 at position 0"